# AgGridReact: Place horizontal scroll at bottom when using side bar

Tags: ag-grid, horizontal-scrolling, ag-grid-react

I'm looking for a way to pin/place the horizontal scroll at the bottom of the grid-area for the situation when the data-content (rows) are collectively shorter than the side bar height.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBayc.png)

[Example link](https://plnkr.co/edit/qunv7YwGuYldxpOvuLVV?p=preview)

I can only see this problem when:

1. using grid options

```html
sideBar={true}
domLayout={'autoHeight'}
```

2. there are too few rows